# the visibility attribute not working in html file

Tags: html

I set the visibility tag on a table to hidden but it is still visible when in display it.I have also tried display:none.
Anyone knows the problem ?

```html
<blockquote>
    <table id="detailsTable"  visibility="hidden">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Employé : Veuillez saisir un nom ou bien un matricule</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      
      
      </tbody>
    </table>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Use CSS, you can't add an attribute called visibility to your table. You could say `visibility: hidden` inside the `style` attribute or in your css file.

Comment: There are nice answers to your question already, but - based on your code sample - I believe you fundamentally failed to understand that "visibility" and "display" are not attributes of the HTML TAG, but parameters of a STYLE attribute. Examples: `<table id="detailsTable" style="display: none;">` or  `<table id="detailsTable" style="visibility: hidden;">`. Without understanding this little piece of information, no answer will help you much. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility is a style property - not a table attribute - just apply the visibility style rule in your css and it will hide.

I have put the styling into the css - and on clicking the button toggle a class. If that class is hide-table - then the visibility: hidden will apply and ... hide the table. I put a border on the table to highlight the states.

**Note that it is always better to apply a style and attach it to a class that is added or removed - rather than using javascript to directly alter the style property on the element.**

```js
function toggleTableVisibility(){
  const table = document.querySelector('#detailsTable');
  table.classList.toggle('hide-table')
}
```

```css
#detailsTable{
  border: solid 1px red;
  visibility:visible
}


#detailsTable.hide-table{
 visibility:hidden
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <table id="detailsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Employé : Veuillez saisir un nom ou bien un matricule</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      
      
      </tbody>
    </table>
</blockquote>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleTableVisibility()">toggle table visiblity</button>
```

Comment: you are quite welcome @kim - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Visibility is a style property - not a table attribute

Use JavaScript to implement it.
Connect the DOM to that
It'll be

```
document.getElementById("detailsTable").style.visibility = "hidden";
```